# How to update PATH environment variable when executing bat file in cmd windows?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

The task is to install the program and several modules. I want to do it through a bat file of something like this

```
python-3.6.4.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers = 1 PrependPath = 1
pip install intelhex-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
pip install pyserial-3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

The problem is that after installing python, the environment variable for the running cmd.exe is not updated, so it does not find the pip program that is installed along with python.

Tell me how to update the PATH variable when executing a bat file from cmd?

Comment: If you're installing the executable with specific options, and without user interaction, then the locations will be the known defaults. There is therefore no need to use variables, or modify any existing ones, use the known default absolute paths instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/windows.html

You can specify the install directory with `DefaultAllUsersTargetDir`.

Also, do not put SPACE characters between the parameter name and value.

```
python-3.6.4.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1
```